# Upload multiple files with single input with AJAX/jQuery/formData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make an upload form with AJAX/jQuery. The problem is i can't upload multiple files from a single input. With this code I can upload 1 file:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':button').click(function(){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 
    $.ajax({
      url: 'upload.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType:"json",
      async: true,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.Result);
      },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
    });
  });
});
```

I changed the `formData` part to this:

```
var formData = new FormData($('input[name^="file"]'));
$.each($('input[name^="file"]')[0].files, function(i, file){
 formData.append(i, file);
});
```

the PHP part:

```
foreach($_FILES as $index => $file)
    {
        // for easy access
        $fileName     = $file['name'];
        // for easy access
        $fileTempName = $file['tmp_name'];
        // check if there is an error for particular entry in array
        if(!empty($file['error'][$index]))
        {
            // some error occurred with the file in index $index
            // yield an error here
            return false;
        }

        // check whether file has temporary path and whether it indeed is an uploaded file
        if(!empty($fileTempName) && is_uploaded_file($fileTempName))
        {
            // move the file from the temporary directory to somewhere of your choosing
            move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, ROOT_DIR . '/uploads/xPhoto/' . $fileName);
            // mark-up to be passed to jQuery's success function.
            echo '<p>Click <strong><a href="uploads/' . $fileName . '" target="_blank">' . $fileName . '</a></strong> to download it.</p>';
        }
    }
```

So my question is, how can I upload multiple files with a single input?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact method of gathering the files in one of my (old) projects.

**HTML**

```
<input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
```

**jQuery**

```
var fd = new FormData();
$.each($('#files')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    fd.append(i, file);
});

// Other form data can be set and passed using:
// fd.append('POST_key', $input_object.val());

$.ajax({
    url: var_your_file_handler,
    type: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false, // tell jquery not to set content type
    ...
)};
```

I believe - it's an old project - that `processData` and `contentType` need to be false in order for the `fd` object to be sent in the request as it would have been during a normal form submission. As long as the AJAX request is POST, files can be gathered in PHP using `$_FILES`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Let's you upload multiple files from single input. All accessible from the $`_FILES` global in php.

```
var formData = new FormData();
var files = $('#files_input').prop('files');

$.each(files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append("file_"  + i, file);
});
```